# undefined method `model_name' for {"..."}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, legacy

I have a settings form and I'm having some issues in passing the data and getting it to save.

I have the following code

routes

```
get 'settings', to: 'settings#index'
put 'settings', to: 'settings#update_all'
```

controller

```
def index
end

def update_all
  params[:setting].keys.each do |index, value|
    setting = Setting.find_by(name: index)
    
    if setting
      setting.value = value
      setting.save
    end
  end
end

private

def setting_params
  params.permit(
    # company details
    :company_name,
    :company_system_display_name,
    :company_address_1,
    :company_address_2,
    :company_address_3,
    :company_address_4,
    :company_postcode,
    :company_default_country_id,
    :company_web_site,
    :company_main_contact,
    :company_main_telephone,
    :company_main_fax,
    :company_main_mail,
    :company_accounts_contact,
    :company_accounts_telephone,
    :company_accounts_fax,
    :company_accounts_mail,
    :delivery_contact_name,
    :setting_delivery_address_1,
    :setting_delivery_address_2,
    :setting_delivery_address_3,
    :setting_delivery_address_4,
    :delivery_postcode,
    :delivery_country_id,

    # tax payroll
    :company_incorporation_status,
    :company_registration_number,
    :number_of_partners,
    :is_vso,
    :company_corporation_tax_number,
    :is_efpm,
    :company_year_end,
    :company_year_end,
    :paye_sender_id,
    :paye_pass,
    :paye_eoy_mail,
    :company_vat_status,
    :company_vat_number,
    :cash_accounting,
    :cash_accounting,
    :vat_adjustment_limit,
    :btp_enabled,
    :btp_api_url,
    :btp_realm,
    :btp_client_id,
    :btp_client_secret,
    :eori_number,
    "Personal Travel",
    "Personal Motoring",
    "Personal Telephone",
    :company_paye_tax_number,
    :rti_start_date,
    :payroll_bacs_sort_code,
    :paye_accounts_office_reference_number,
    :econ,
    :week_end_day,
    :weekly_pay_day,
    :payroll_first_two_week_pay_date,
    :payroll_first_four_week_pay_date,
    :standard_sp_recovery_rate,
    :nic_compensation,
    :hmrc_employers_nic_allowance,

    # system settings
    :bcc_address,
    :check_stock_levels,
    :default_purchase_invoice_price_type,
    :discounts_enabled,
    :enable_custom_documents,
    :doc_layout,
    :nav_type,
    :valid_for,
    :quote_value,
    :default_true_create_supply_orders,
    "exclude_non-manufactured_from_wo_creation_from_so",
    :remove_works_order_from_plan_after_edit,
    :include_sales_order_notes_on_picking_lists,
    :user_change_own_password,
    :auto_populate_receive_invoice,
    :assume_supplier_has_vat_number_for_auto_populate_receive_invoice,
    :backorder_default,
    :consolidate_work_order,
    :over_delivery_default,
    :use_package_lines,
    :hightlight_below_order_quantity_on_grn,
    :show_poi_descriptions_on_order_lines,
    # VAT RATES
    :default_stock_item_vat_rate_id,
    :margin_markup,
    :restrict_purchase_invoice_query_flag,
    :update_probability_on_opportunity_status_change,
    :default_stock_item_vat_rate_id,
    :enable_comments_on_stock_components,
    :no_supplier_serial_numbers,
    :enable_batch_number_generation,
    :intrastat_enable,
    :intrastat_enable_tod,
    :wo_process_start_time,
    :negative_current_stock,
    "default_customer_payment_term_id",
    "default_supplier_payment_term_id",
    :min_supplier_payment,
    :show_vat_on_uninvoiced_sales,
    :hide_due_date_on_sales_quotes_and_orders,
    :hide_due_date_on_purchase_quotes_and_orders,
    :inherit_default_sales_accounts,
    :logo_position,
    :company_logo,
    :company_logo_image_file,
    :company_logo_image_file,
    :kpi_plan_vat_rate,
    :kpi_plan_payroll_rate,
    :kpi_use_average_cos,
    :kpi_use_average_labour,
    :sales_order_item_custom_info_1_form_name,
    :sales_order_item_custom_info_1_enabled,

    # trade terms
    :terms_of_trade,

    # factoring
    :factor_type,
    :factor_user,
    :factor_pass,
    :factoring_image_file,
    :default_repair_order_stock_item_id,
    :default_repair_stock_location_id,
    :default_repair_labour_stock_item_id,

    # document storage
    :document_storage_type,
    :dropbox_access_token,

    # web api
    :api_url,
    :api_key,
    :api_enabled
  )
end
```

index

```
<% content_for :title, "Edit Setting" %>

<div class="l-12col">
    <h1>Edit Settings</h1>
</div>

<%= render partial: "form", locals: { setting: @setting, submit_text: "Update" } %>
```

form

```
<div class="l-12col" id="settings_form">
  <%= form_with model: setting, url: settings_path, method: :put, multipart: true do |f| %>
    <div class="tabs">
      <!-- start tab headings -->
      <div class="tab-headings">
        <a class="tab-button active" data-id="company_details">Company Details</a>
        <a class="tab-button" data-id="tax_payroll">Tax &amp; Payroll</a>
        <a class="tab-button" data-id="system_settings">System Settings</a>
        <a class="tab-button" data-id="trade_terms">Trade Terms</a>
        <a class="tab-button" data-id="factoring">Factoring</a>
        <a class="tab-button" data-id="document_storage">Document Storage</a>

        <% if Features.API? %>
          <a class="tab-button" data-id="web_api">Web API</a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <!-- end tab headings -->

      <div class="tab-contents">
        <!-- start of company_details tab -->
        <div class="tab-content active" id="company_details">
          <div class="l-row-block clearfix">
            <div class="l-06col l-ml-12col l-md-12col">
              <h2 class="txt-title-alt">
                Name &amp; Address

                <span data-tooltip title="Full legal name and address for this business as it should appear on business documentation.">
                  <span class="icon-help-with-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
              </h2>

              <div class='field l-margin-sm'>
                <%= f.label :company_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
              </div>

              <div class='field l-margin-sm checkbox_form'>
                <%= f.check_box :company_incorporation_status %>
                <%= f.label :company_incorporation_status, "Incorporated?" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of company_details tab -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btns">
      <%= submit_tag submit_text, id: 'company_settings_update_btn' %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: "btn-medium" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Database structure
[image]

Error:

```
NoMethodError at /settings
undefined method `model_name' for {"quote_format"=>"QU-%5n", "quote_value"=>1, "company_name"=>"Your Business Name", "company_address_1"=>"Address Line 1", "company_address_2"=>"Address Line 2", "company_address_3"=>"Address Line 3", "company_address_4"=>"Address Line 4", "company_postcode"=>"Postcode", "company_main_contact"=>"Your Name", "company_main_telephone"=>"Your Telephone Number", "company_main_fax"=>"Your Fax Number", "company_main_mail"=>"Your e-Mail", "company_accounts_contact"=>"", "company_accounts_telephone"=>"", "company_accounts_fax"=>"", "company_accounts_mail"=>"", "company_web_site"=>"Your Web Site", "company_incorporation_status"=>true, "company_registration_number"=>"", "company_corporation_tax_number"=>"", "company_paye_tax_number"=>"",
```

This is a legacy app I've just re-built the form and trying to get it working again to me the DB structure is strange and personally I would properly use ActiveRecord::Store for this but as we can't change anything in the DB that's a no-go.

So if anyone has any ideas that'll be great.

EDIT: After the changes above I now have the following

```
NoMethodError at /settings
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

Hint: Something is `nil` when it probably shouldn't be.
```

EDIT 2:
When running `rails c` I get the following

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 5793
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.3.2)
[1] pry(main)> @settings
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> @setting
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> Setting.all
  Setting Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings`
=> [#<Setting:0x000056318efee410
  id: 1,
  name: "quote_format",
  value: "QU-%5n",
  value_type: "string",
  created_at: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 20:49:16.000000000 BST +01:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 20:49:16.000000000 BST +01:00,
  created_by: nil,
  updated_by: nil>,
 #<Setting:0x000056318f1b2df0
  id: 2,
  name: "quote_value",
  value: "1",
  value_type: "integer",
  created_at: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 20:49:16.000000000 BST +01:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 13 Jul 2021 20:49:16.000000000 BST +01:00,
  created_by: nil,
  updated_by: nil>,
 #<Setting:0x000056318f1b2c10
  id: 3,
....
```

Comment: What Rails version are you using, and what's `@settings`?

Comment: Please include the error messages as text and not screenshots. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: You're not showing us where you're defining `@settings` and the error message pretty much tells you exactly what you have to do to remedy the problem - pass an instance of Setting instead of a hash. `setting = Setting.find_by(name: :company_name)` is also most likely a bug as you're looking up  `WHERE name = "company_name"`.

Comment: Made some changes to the question @SebastianPalm

Comment: Made some changes to  the question @max

Comment: @SebastianPalma This app was built way back with Rails 2, then moved to rails 5 and now with Rails 6 where everything has decided to go crazy, I'm not the original creator I'm just working on the refactoring

Comment: In Rails 5.1+ you should use `form_with` which replaces `form_for` and `form_tag` with a single interface.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I was wondering that myself, I've changed it to `form_with` now and updated the code in the question to reflect that

Comment: I'm also not able to make any sense of the db schema or the controller. Is what we are seeing in the screenshot the "settings table"? Is settings a "singleton" so that there is only one row? Why do you need to loop across the hash and look them up one by one? That would make sense if it was an EAV pattern but I can't get it to make sense with the schema.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yeah so that is the settings table in the screenshot, so it has three fields `name`, `value` and `value_type` value_type sets the type of setting ie. string, boolean etc. Like I said this was built way back in rails 2 (there isn't even proper strong params, I'm adding them in) so the db structure is questionable for sure I'm just dealing with what I've been given.. Settings is a singleton so one per row, as I'm trying to save all the settings I assumed I would need to loop through and save each one, but if you have a better way I'm, all ears, have to be weary of current data

Comment: Also in terms of making sense of the schema haha you and me both @SebastianPalma there's a lot of questionable things been done here and unfortunately DB wise I'm stuck with that I have

Comment: As per the last error you're getting, you have to check what `@settings` currently holds in order to work with `form_with` as max suggested. Most probably is the internals of the framework expecting to receive a hash to retrieve the keys, but `@settings` is something else.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've added the rails console output as well as made a few slight tweaks to the code `index` and `form` let me know if that helps.

Comment: Also @max my bad for tagging the wrong username haha

Comment: Ah sorry - now I see thats its an EAV table.  You can start by eliminating n+1 read queries by doing `settings = Setting.where(name: setting_params)` to load them all at once instead of using `find_by`. Updating the settings will still probally be one query per attribute but you should wrap the entire thing in a transaction. I would move this code into a seperate object such as a service object or a model that wraps the collection of settings so that you can test it. I think you unfortunately have quite a bit of work left here.

Comment: @max Would it be possible to provide an example? As I'm really struggling here to get  my head around this haha, I can deal with CRUD functionality all day but a form that's this big and saving all this data is really racking my brain haha or do a live chat if your free to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of playing around with the code, here's what worked.

form

```
<%= form_with(model: setting, scope: :settings, method: :post, multipart: true) do |f| %>
```

controller

```rb
def index
  settings = {}

  Setting.all.each do |setting|
    settings[setting.name] = setting.value
  end

  @settings = OpenStruct.new(settings)
end

def update
  @errors = []
  @error_list = []

  params[:settings].each do |name, value|
    setting = Setting.find_by(name: name)
    next unless setting.present?

    setting.update(value: value)
  end

  redirect_to settings_path, notice: 'Settings have been updated'
end
```

Now to get the errors and other fields working.